# Превращение всего в объекты в виртуальной машине для языка программирования

Tags: объекты, любой-язык, виртуальная-машина

Пишу простую стековую виртуальную машину для обучения, в ней есть несколько типов:

`double`,`float`,`int`,`long`,`bool` и `object`.

Сейчас строки - это объект, объект - это интерфейс со своими функциями. Пример:

```
get_field(this,string name),
call_field(this,string name)
```

В стеке числа хранятся как `Value::Int,Value::Long`. Недавно всплыла такая мысль, как хранение чисел в объекте, т.е `Value::Int,Value::Long` и т.д. пропадут и останется только `object`.

Насколько это хорошая/плохая мысль?

Comment: хорошая/плохая мысль если смотреть с какой стороны?

Comment: Простота использования, и наверное скорость работы? Я больше смотрю на JVM при создании этой машины, и в java int,long и прочее это примитивные типы, но мне например не понятно почему так если можно их тоже сделать объектами

Comment: @DestinyPlayer, объект - это «упаковка» для типов. Чтобы произвести с объектом какие-либо действия, Вам должно будет его распаковать. Так зачем тратить лишние действия, если можно сразу хранить те же примитивы явно?

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, а зачем тогда упаковывать строки и все остальное? ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно, всё можно представить как "объект", но если рассмотреть такие языки как C# или Java, можно заметить, что в них существуют и примитивные типы, например, те самые числовые `int`, `double` и прочие, которые в целях оптимизации не стоит без лишней надобности рассматривать как обобщенные объекты.

Для целей обучения можно как обобщить все возможные типы и рассматривать их как объекты (это в некоторой части должно упростить код), так и наоборот использовать разделение, чтобы построить систему более близкую к реально используемым в промышленном масштабе.

Здесь также стоит упомянуть механизмы *boxing/unboxing* и дополнительные типы-значения (задаваемые ключевым словом `struct`) в C#.